# Ubuntu 22.04 resource (cpu, ram, swap) issues

Tags: 22.04, docker, nodejs, resource-limiting

I am on a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 installation on a ThinkPad E15 (16gb ram, 512gb ssd, i710510U@1.8GHz x8, Radeon 550x).

The system is used to run 7 docker containers and multiple node processes (in multiple terminator shells) as well as one Firefox and WebStorm instance for web development. In general everything works fine and under idle I average 15% CPU usage, 10GB ram and 1.8GB/2.1GB swap allocation.

During (re)build processes or testing everything spikes to 100% load. The system freezes for 2-10 minutes (or permanently) and processes get forcibly shut down (system-oomd normally kills Firefox and one shell, not necessarily the one that runs the intensive process). Sometimes the same seems to happen on video calls.

Question: Is there a known problem with resource allocation and can I somehow fix this? Are there ways to better troubleshoot my problem? During the system freeze I can't even switch to pure shell as far as I can see.

Disclaimer: This is my first time on a Linux machine after multiple years of absence, please excuse my half baked terminology and knowledge)

Comment: The E-series ThinkPads generally have slower storage speeds compared to the T or X series, but one area to look at first would be to increase your swap to something closer to 16~24GB given the description of the problem. Physical RAM would go a long way to helping with Docker containers, though, as they tend to lean towards using memory more than disk caching.

Comment: Thank you so much, pushing swap above 20GB seems to have done the trick.